# Javascript - File uploading, readAsArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, filereader

i'm currently trying to upload a file to my server. But i'm not really sure how to do this with **readAsArrayBuffer**. This works if I use **readAsBinaryString**.

If i try to console.log it only returns **'arrayBuffer: {}'.**
After I've tried to upload it, i can see inside post that  only a empty object was sent. If I use readAsBinaryString, I see a bunch of binary code.

```
var file = document.getElementById('my_file').files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(e){
        console.log(e.target.result);
        $scope.image = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

How can I see my file, so I know it's working when using readAsArrayBuffer? 
If more code is needed let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Try to log the length of the buffer `console.log(e.target.result.byteLength)`. The code is likely to be working but the console representation of an `ArrayBuffer` is just `arrayBuffer: {}`, and not a bunch of binary stuff.

Comment: dreyescat - Thanks, yes, now I get some output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload am image then you have to convert it into base64 format. You can do it either by using canvas element or by using Filereader.If you are using Filereader then you have to use `readAsDataURL()`

You can refer MDN for this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL

also you can use canvas element
[Convert an image to canvas that is already loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212792/convert-an-image-to-canvas-that-is-already-loaded)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm planning on using fileReader. I'll have a form with some input fields, including a file input. Then I want to send the form data including the image with POST. Is readAsDataURL still the way to go?

Comment: yes why not? readAsDataURL is just  a way to convert image it into base64 format string. You can store it in variable and Post it in form or store it in database

Answer (score 9):

According to [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) documentation

> You can not directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer; instead, you create one of the typed array objects or a DataView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer.

So as I commented before probably `console.log` doesn't know how to represent the buffer and therefore it simply outputs `arrayBuffer: {}`.

If you want to show something in the console you need to use a typed array or a DataView. For example using an `Int8Array`:

```
reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(new Int8Array(e.target.result));
};
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wnw8cL5r/2/)